# How can we vary the electric field?

Tags: electric-fields

The causes of electric field are electric charges or a variation of magnetic field. But what causes the electric field to vary? If we want to make a variation of electric field , what can we do for the electric charge ?

Comment: Do you mean, "How do you produce a time-varying electric field?"

Comment: One could charge a comb electrostatically with your hair and then move it up and down. Or to and fro. I have this as a lecture demonstration...

Comment: A capacitor, during the process of charging creates a time-varying electric field between its plates. Also if the variation of the magnetic field with time be non-linear, Maxwell's equation will dictate that it will produce a time-varying electric field.

Comment: probably_someone yes thats what I mean . Pieter so if we move the charges , the electric field would vary in direction only not in magnitude ? SRS its because number of charges changes so it implies that the strength of electric field changes . Thank u all

Comment: Then the above comments are good examples. A general answer is posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are, in general, two ways to produce a time-varying electric field:

1.) Move some charges around; or

2.) Create oscillating magnetic fields.

Comment: If moving electric charges produces a variation in electric field , and as atoms are in continuous motion so we are always surrounded with this variation how do we feel it?

Comment: The reason we don't feel it is because there are tons of atoms moving in tons of different directions, and on average the electric fields they produce cancel out. That said, we can *detect* this random motion at the microscopic level - in atomic spectra, *pressure broadening* increases the width of a spectral line due to random deformations of the atom from the electric field of its neighbors.

Comment: How does the electromagnetic field affects the potential of an atom ?